# Deployment of application which uses apache 2.0 libraries

Tags: licensing, apache-license

I need to publicly deploy web app which uses apache 2.0 libraries. The license obliges me to provide credits in case of redistribution. Do I need to do this in such a case. Is it considered redistribution? Are there any best practices in such a case?

What about javascript parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a *deployment* is not a *distribution*. You are obliged to follow the rules for *distribution* only if you're allowing people to download and install your application.

Comment: So native Android or iOS app (distributed, installed) is not the same as web browser app (deployed on the server, then just loaded into browser)?